# Imprimir claims do Owin Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

Como eu consigo imprimir todos os diferentes tipos de `claims` que eu criei durante a minha autenticação pelo Owin Identity?
Estou usando `@User.Identity.Nome` para conseguir imprimir somente o nome, não consigo ter acesso as demais claims que eu criei.

Atualmente, tenho a seguinte classe de login:

```
if (ad.Autentica(Usuario) == true) // SE AUTENTICAR, FAZ O LOGIN
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Usuario.Login),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Usuario.Nome),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, Usuario.Sobrenome),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Usuario.Departamento),
    }, "SgwCookie");

    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.returnUrl) || Url.IsLocalUrl(model.returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(model.returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você consegue obter todas as claims associadas a um usuário com o seguinte código.

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //Cria um lista de todas claims do usuario.
    var cliams = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims.ToList();
}
```

Assim você tem todas as claims do usuário e pode fazer as validações necessárias.

> Imprimindo no cshtml

```
<ul>
@foreach (var claim in ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims)
{
    <li>@claim.Type : @claim.Value</li>

}
</ul>
```

Comment: não tem como eu imprimir o valor dessa claim diretamente no .cshtml?

Comment: Sim é possivel, vou colocar no final da resposta

Comment: Não é possível uma específica, sem o foreach? Igual o que acontece com @User.Identity.Name

Comment: Você pode usar ```((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("claimType").value```

Comment: Ainda não consegui imprimir o conteúdo da claim. Resolvi o que queria passando o conteúdo que quero para variáveis de sessão diretamente no controlador de login... Mas imagino que não seja a melhor forma